# Spring JPA, Many to Many Cannot fetch from the non Owning Entity

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a many to many relationship between User and Role entities. When I create roles and a user then save them and add to user, I can fetch the associated roles from User instance, but cannot fetch users from the Role instance.

I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.6, JPA and Kotlin.
Here is my code.

Entities

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,

    val email: String,
    var name: String,
    val contactNumber: String,

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")]
    )
    @JsonBackReference
    var roles: MutableSet<Role> = mutableSetOf(),
)

@Entity
data class Role(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,

    var name: String,
    var description: String,

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
    @JsonBackReference
    var users: MutableSet<User> = mutableSetOf(),
)
```

Repository

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    fun findFirstByEmail(email: String) : User?
}

@Repository
interface RoleRepository : JpaRepository<Role, Long>{
    fun findFirstByName(name: String) : Role?
}
```

Test Method

```
@DataJpaTest
class UserEntityTests(@Autowired val userRepository: UserRepository,
                      @Autowired val roleRepository: RoleRepository) {

 @Test
    fun `test many-to-many relationship with roles`() {

        val role1 = Role(
            name = "Admin",
            description = "Admin Role"
        )
        val role2 = Role(
            name = "User",
            description = "User Role"
        )
        roleRepository.saveAll(listOf(role1, role2))

        var user = User(
            email = "jerry@example.com",
            name = "Jerry Garcia",
            contactNumber = "4444444444",
        )
        user.roles = mutableSetOf(role1, role2)
        userRepository.save(user)

        val savedUser = userRepository.findById(user.id).get()
        assertEquals(2, savedUser.roles.size)

        val savedRole1 = roleRepository.findById(role1.id).get()
        val savedRole2 = roleRepository.findById(role2.id).get()
        assertEquals(1, savedRole1.users.size)
        assertEquals(1, savedRole2.users.size)
    }
}
```

So the first assertion passed but the second one fails.
If change the order of saving where I save the user first and save it along with the Role, then the second assertion pass but first one fails (need to interchange the order of assertion as well)

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Update: If I tried to save both entities with the relation entity that gives a stack overflow error as expected.

Comment: If I query like this, then it returns the users as expected.
```
val role = roleRepository.findFirstByName("Role 1")
role?.let { userRepository.findUsersByRolesContains(it) }
```